# Why are Visualforce pages rendered empty on site?

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites

I have a Visualforce page.

While developing, and in /apex/ , it looks fine (still in development)

[image]

corresponding code is:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" StandardController="ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c">
<apex:sectionHeader title="Choose your plan" subtitle="New Order"/>
  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
  <apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock title="Order Edit" mode="edit">
  <apex:pageblockButtons >
  <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Submit"/>
    <apex:commandButton action="Cancel" value="Cancel"/>

  </apex:pageblockButtons>
  <apex:pageblocksection >


  <apex:inputField value="{!ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c.ChargentOrders__Payment_Method__c}"/>

  <apex:inputField value="{!ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c.ChargentOrders__Charge_Amount__c}"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c.ChargentOrders__Billing_First_Name__c}"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c.ChargentOrders__Billing_Last_Name__c}"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c.ChargentOrders__Billing_Address__c}"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c.ChargentOrders__Billing_Zip_Postal__c}"/>



  <apex:inputField value="{!ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c.ChargentOrders__Card_Number__c}"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c.ChargentOrders__Card_Security_Code__c}"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c.ChargentOrders__Card_Type__c}"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c.ChargentOrders__Card_Month_Indicator__c}"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c.ChargentOrders__Card_Expiration_Year__c}"/>


  </apex:pageblocksection>

</apex:pageblock>
  </apex:form> 

  <!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
</apex:page>
```

**Problem**

My problem is that, when I add this page, to a public site I created, the page is rendered with NO input fields visible.

[image]

The Site's public access settings, include Read/Edit/Create for the said object

[image]

The only thing I think can still be an issue, is the Controller of the object, if there is any settings on that to add/do?

- The site has Guest User License
- Login - Not Allowed

Where should I check next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Inputfield tag hence would recommend you to check the field level security and make sure fields are visible for guest user profile .

Click on sites label and click on public access settings to modify the field level security

Comment: This is a Site Guest User. It does not show on the "Standard" or "Custom" profiles, hence I can't modify single fields access.

Comment: you can click on sites label and click on public access settings to modify the field level security.I hope i am clear for you sir

Answer (score 0):

As Monith mentioned it uses Site Guest User permissions.

If you don’t want to expose write permissions for external users, you can use  inputText fields on v. page and in controller  to invoke apex web service that runs in a system mode (as Admin) and to insert / update you objects

Eric